# How to use Bluetooth headphones as only output?

Tags: audio, bluetooth-audio

While using phone mic as input. My Bluetooth headphones don't support stereo and mic at the same time so I wondering if I could use phone mic while using Bluetooth headphones. I tried using SoundAbout but that doesn't work for wireless. Pls help.